# Changing keyboard rate for initial keypress in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

I currently have the settings as follows:

```
Repeat Keys:
Delay: SHORT (all the way to the left)
Speed: FAST (all the way to the right)
```

This works okay in the sense that if I press a key, it will after a few seconds, repeat quickly. The problem is, the initial keypress. If I press and hold a key, I want there to be NO delay and it to immediately start repeating the key quickly! The delay seems to be only relevant to the keypresses following the original keypress.

How do I get my keypress repeat to be very fast from the very first keypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy with dconf editor. (To install run `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`). Open dconf editor and navigate to:

org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>keyboard

Here the "delay" can be set in miliseconds. Do not set zero, I just had a little play and 10 ms it is impossible to type without getting 2-3 letters. Play around with this number (it updates instantly once you have entered the new number. If you enter a value that is too low and you cant type in a sensible one you can use the reset to default button.

Comment: Didnt work for me. Not sure how to get to the screen after installing Dconf?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. Looks like it does work.

Answer (score 3):

> This is easy with dconf editor. (To install run `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`). Open dconf editor and navigate to:
>
> org>gnome>settings-daemon>peripherals>keyboard

The location for keyboard delay has been updated to:

> org>gnome>desktop>peripherals>keyboard

Changing the delay to 200ms worked well for me.